# JavaFX ListView lambda

Tags: java, listview, javafx, lambda

I would like to have this ListView's event handled in a lambda:

```
lvSelModel.selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> changed, String oldVal, String newVal) {
        //display the selection
        response.setText("Computer selected is " + newVal);
    }
});
```

Here is an example with a button:

Original anonymous class:

```
btnUp.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {
        response.setText("you pressed UP");
    }
});
```

Same result but a Lambda:

```
btnDown.setOnAction( (ae) -> response.setText("you pressed DOWN"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is exactly the same as with the button. The difference is that this time we need to write a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) that declares 3 parameters (the three parameters of the functional `changed` method) instead of one:

```
lvSelModel.selectedItemProperty()
          .addListener((changed, oldVal, newVal) -> response.setText("Computer selected is " + newVal));
```

`changed` parameter will be bound to `ObservableValue<? extends String>` and `oldVal` and `newVal` will be bound to `String`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I had incorrect Lambda parameters when I tried.